# Triggering next intent without user input in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm building my first chatbot using Dialogflow. During my chat sessions, I would like to move on from one intent to another, without having user input in between. This can be seen in this image on [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzDwm.png).

The layout of the chat so far can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip5B4.png).

I'm supposed to move from showing the video or article directly to "allright has your car..." without any user input, but I don't seem to be able to. How do I solve this?

I've tried using in and output contexts, but that didn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Events can be triggered through Dialogflow **fulfillment** or the
>   **detect intent API**. These events can be handled in your Dialogflow agent or in fulfillment.

Check documentation here: [Dialogflow Events](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-custom)

This means you will need to programmatically do this